# Java NoClassDefFoundError can't compile

Tags: java, compilation, noclassdeffounderror

i have a problem with java. After compile the main class Main.java, with the command 
`javac Main.java`
i use the command

```
java Main
```

in the same directory where the Main.class is located, and i see this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: main/Main)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: add your class code too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have created your class in package `main`. You need to use the following command to run program:

```
java main.Main
```

Comment: But the package main is in a folder named bin....why the command
.../bin: $ java main.Main
work,but the command
..../: $ java bin.main.Main 
doesn't work?

Comment: Try to set the classpath and run.

Comment: @user3694151, if you don't specify a classpath explicitly, the system takes the current directory as base, and looks for the classes from there. That's the reason it works when you are in bin directory.